# Can I more efficiently search for the first triangle number with >500 divisors? Why is my current implementation slow?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, math

I'm working on Project Euler [problem 12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12)

> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

I know for certain that it can produce correct answers for smaller numbers. For example if I replace `> 500` with `== 6`, the output result I get is an expected `28`.

For 500 divisors, about two minutes into the execution, the program begins to run very slowly. I believe every variable here is being overwritten at each iteration.  Why is it slow?  I have tried separating into functions to make use of local variables, but this doesn't improve the running time.

Code:

```
import sys

currentNumber, currentCalculationNumber, divisorCount, naturalNumber = 1, 1, 0, 1

while True:

    while currentCalculationNumber <= currentNumber:
        if currentNumber % currentCalculationNumber == 0:
            divisorCount += 1
        currentCalculationNumber += 1
    if divisorCount > 500:
        print ("ANSWER: " , currentNumber)
        sys.exit(0)

    naturalNumber += 1
    currentNumber += naturalNumber
    currentCalculationNumber, divisorCount = 1, 0
```

Comment: Nothing. That's just the nature of this problem. Notice that to have more than 500 divisors a number must be higher (much higher in fact) than 2**500 = 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589376 (but not higher than 500!). You need a different approach to solve this problem in reasonable time.

Comment: you're checking _every single number_ below the current value. So when you check 1000, you run 999 `while` loops. At the bare minimum, you only really need to go up to the square root of your current value - if a number less than the square root is a divisor, it has a corresponding divisor greater than the square root.

Comment: @Błotosmętek: A number doesn't have to be anywhere near that big to have over 500 divisors. For example, `2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19*23` has 512 divisors.

Comment: I stand corrected - I somehow got a misconception that the problem involves **prime** divisors only. Still, a brute force approach to this problem is a Bad Idea.

Comment: Please try to make question titles distinctive to the individual question being asked -- if you could have two questions with the same title where the answer to one isn't useful in helping someone answer the other, then the title is insufficiently specific. I've attempted to edit towards that end here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slowness is from your brute-force method of counting divisors.  The solution is on the order of 10^8, so you're iterating through that inner `while` loop on the order of 10^16 times: the nested loops make an **O(n)** process.  This is going to take a while.  You need something more efficient, at least **O**(n log(n) ).

One of the purposes of Project Euler is to get us to investigate more efficient algorithms.  For this one, you'll likely want to use the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), which will require any of the numerous prime-generation functions.

You should develop a "bag of tricks" module that you `import` for most problems.  In fact, you should already have one that generates prime numbers, from earlier problems (assuming that you're attacking them in some order).  If not, try [this one](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/366178/).

Comment: means to say that this is an O(n^2) process as there is nested looping

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Prune's answer but here is a faster version of your brute-force algorithm:

### VERSION 1 (slower, brute-forse using numpy)

```
import numpy as np
i = 1
f = lambda N: (N * (N + 1)) // 2
ndmax = 0

while True:
    t = f(i)
    p = np.arange(1, t + 1)
    r = np.mod(t, p)
    nd = p.size - np.count_nonzero(r) + 1
    if nd > ndmax: # track progress
        ndmax = nd
        print((i, t, nd))
    if nd > 500:
        print ("ANSWER: " , t)
        break
    i += 1
```

### VERSION 2 (Fast, using sympy's `divisor_count`)

```
from sympy import divisor_count
import numpy as np
i = 1
f = lambda N: (N * (N + 1)) // 2
ndmax = 0

while True:
    t = f(i)
    nd = divisor_count(t)
    if nd > ndmax: # track progress
        ndmax = nd
        print((i, t, nd))
    if nd > 500:
        print ("ANSWER: " , t)
        break
    i += 1
```

For more details see [`divisor_count`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html) and reference therein.